# if $query = value?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've got a little problem and I don't  kno how to solve this. 
I want to check what rights have the account who is connected.
In my Database, The rights are written with int, like this : 1 -> admin, 
2 -> moderator, 3 -> redactor, 4 -> user. 
I'm trying to check like this, but I don't know how to write the "if($query==1)", I tried a few things, but none of them worked...

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','projet');
$query = "SELECT rights FROM user WHERE pseudo_user ='{$_SESSION['login']}'";
$res = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
if($res=="1")
    {
    echo ('<a href="page_admin.php">Administration</a>');
    echo "<br>";
    }
```

Comment: does the query actually succeed

Comment: Please read a basic tutorial about using mysqli and you'll see how to execute queries in the database. Currently you're not executing anything. Also don't concatenate strings, use parameters.

Comment: did you execute the query: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: you do not even run the query. lol

Comment: Yes, the querry succed.

Comment: @LucienSerre-Fortier mind showing me your table structure?

Comment: `mysqli_query()` doesn't return a string. It returns a `mysqli_result` object, which you can use with `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to get a row of results as an associative array. Look at any mysqli tutorial and you'll see how to use it.

Comment: In the user table, I have the name, login, password, the rights (as an integer from 1 to 4) and the mail. I'm not showing it here because it's not in english, and the name are different than thoose I gave in the example to be understood more easily.

Comment: Why don't you let the SQL check the rights then just check if you get a successful response? `SELECT rights FROM user WHERE pseudo_user ='{$_SESSION['login']}' and rights = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch the results from `$res`.

```
$res = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
if ($row && $row['rights'] == "1")
{
    echo ('<a href="page_admin.php">Administration</a>');
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it did worked.
 I'm not good in php, I'm trying to learn and I'm didn't understand this, but now I've got it, thanks !